# How do I not use the global include files in php

Tags: php

How can I simplify the inclusion of classes in the following code, without
use a global include files.

```
enter code here
<?php
 include "class/class.Prode.php";
 include "class/class.Groupes.php";
 include "class/class.Pages.php";
 include "class/class.Links.php";
 $prod = new Prode;
 $group = new Groups;
 $page = new Pages;
 $link = new Links;
 ?>
```

Please explain and refer to articles describing this.

Comment: i believe thats as simple as it will get? unless you want some type of recursive include (eg, include everyfile in class folder)

Comment: You need an autoloader.  Look at spl_autoload_register()

Comment: google it, [php autoload](http://bit.ly/ZBnVbp), also see [psr-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)

Comment: If you use some package or library you can include it using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at PHP's Autoload: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

It will significantly help simplify your inclusion process!

Answer (score 1):

Use [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) of classes as described in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using PHP's autoload function, I have included an example below for you.

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
$class_name = strtolower($class_name); // you may need to omit this or rename your files
$file =  "class.{$class_name}.php";
$directory = "/path/to/your/class/directory/";

if($full_path = recursive_file_exists($file, $directory)) {
    require($full_path);
} else {
    // check if it exists with an s on the end
            // a nice fallback to cover forgetfulness
    $file =  "class.{$class_name}s.php";
    if($full_path = recursive_file_exists($file, $directory)) {
        require($full_path);
    } else {
        die("The file class.{$class_name}.php could not be found in the location ".$directory);
    }
```

Hope that helps you on your way.